# I need a shader solution to render 3D objects like an animated Blueprint

Tags: rendering, shaders

I am compositing video of 3D machine parts into an After Effects project where all the objects have white lines delineating their edges [ external outlines AND internal edges ].

I would like to animate the machine parts so they match the 2D illustrator graphics of the rest of the project. There must be a shader that can do this? Ideally with solid filled faces, not transparent.

Comment: Do you want to see the edges through the filled faces?  (perhaps attenuated, or dotted). An illustration of your desired style might help.

Comment: Agree, it'd be good for you to [edit] this question with some examples

Comment: Actually the freestyle page in the manual has an example file for blueprint renders - the Martin M-130 https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/introduction.html

Comment: The solution turned out to be the FREESTYLE NPR renderer. Thank you Allen Simpson for your tip to look there. And thank you to the other responders as well. So appreciated.